# Concatenate String

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function quickCardRegister_OnCompleteSave() {

      publishContent('This is a description',#{imagePath},'http://www.lala.com');
   }
</script>
```

The imagePath variable is populated with value: http://localhost/img/30_w130px.gif

I'm having the following script error: missing ) after argument list

publishContent('This is a description',http://localhost/img/30_w130px.gif,'http://www.lala.com');

How can i surround http://localhost/img/30_w130px.gif with quotes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are in some kinds of template language..

Have you try quote at #{imagePath} ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function quickCardRegister_OnCompleteSave() {

  publishContent('This is a description','#{imagePath}','http://www.lala.com');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the missing '}' at the end for the function just before the closing script tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function quickCardRegister_OnCompleteSave() {

      publishContent('This is a description',#{imagePath},'http://www.lala.com');
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
publishContent('This is a description','"' + #{imagePath} + '"','http://www.lala.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `}` for your function as well as `+` for javascript concatenation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function quickCardRegister_OnCompleteSave() {

      publishContent('This is a description' + #{imagePath} + 'http://www.lala.com');
   }
</script>
```

And I assume `#{imagePath}` something you would replace dynamically.